PHP function made to query database returning three times more results
I wrote a function to query a database and return an array that contains the results. The issue is the function is returning 3x the results in the array when it returns a result. In the case below, you pass a array into the function, then it breaks off the element its going to add to the query (which is a comma delimited string of primary keys to another table). In the example below, the number 1 is passed into it, which should return 1 result in the array; but what is happening is its returning the 1 result 3 times in the array.
I checked the page that takes the result of the function and echos it out into the page, and the returned array does include 3 results, with the correct result just showing in 3 array elements. I'm at a loss as to what is causing this, anyone have ideas?
The code for one of the function is below:
function inqQuery($rptQueryResult4) {
require "../include/dbh.inc.php";
try {
    $inqList = $rptQueryResult4['rpt_inq_string'];
    $inq_arr = explode(",",$inqList);
    $inStmt4 = str_repeat('?,',count($inq_arr) - 1) . '?';
    $inqQuery = "SELECT prop_dba_name AS property_name, dba_name AS mgt_co, CAST(`inq.create_ts` AS DATE) AS inquiry_date
        FROM property_data, enterprise_data, rpt_inquiries, tenant_reports
        WHERE rpt_inquiries.linked_prop_id = property_data.property_id AND rpt_inquiries.linked_ent_id = enterprise_data.ent_id AND rpt_inquiries.inquiry_id IN($inStmt4);";
    $results_inqQuery = $pdo->prepare($inqQuery);
    $results_inqQuery->execute($inq_arr);
    $arrInqQuery = $results_inqQuery->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $arrInqQuery;

} catch (PDOException $e) {
    die("Query Failed: " . $e->getMessage());
}

}
When the array is put into the function, the resulting output should be 1 array element. The function does return the 1 expected array element, but its showing up 3 times in the array instead of once. I have similar functions for different table results and all functions are returning 3x the expected results.

Could be a silly question but are you sure the data isn't 3 times in the db?

Either the reason from the question linked at the top, or you simply forgot a condition for one of joins
